# First click - change ul height, second click - reset height

Tags: javascript, css

I need the button to change ul height (first click - minimize (make height:0px;) and second click - maximize (make height:100px))

```
<button> minimize / maximize</button>
<ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
</ul>
<style>
ul {
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7etcmrcL/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toggle class on ul :

JavaScript :

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
    $('ul').toggleClass('maximize');
        $('ul').toggleClass('minimize');
    });
$('ul').addClass('minimize');
})();
```

CSS :

```
ul {
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.maximize{
    height:200px;
}
.minimize{
    height:0px;

}
```

HTML :

```
<button> minimize / maximize</button>
    <ul>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>123</li>
    </ul>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vikashvverma/7etcmrcL/3/

Comment: No `jQuery` tag and not even mentioned that use `jQuery`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

See comments inline in the code:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var clickCount = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-clicked'), 10);
    // Get clicked count from the data attribute

    if (clickCount++ % 2) {
        // If clicked count odd
        document.getElementById('myUl').style.height = '0px';
    } else {
        // if clicked count is even
        document.getElementById('myUl').style.height = '100px';
    }
    this.setAttribute('data-clicked', clickCount);
    // Updated clicked count by one
}, false);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7etcmrcL/5/)